# IntelliJ support for MapStruct in a Bazel Project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bazel, mapstruct, annotation-processing

I'm having issues getting IntelliJ to recognize MapStruct generated files in a Bazel project. When I build the Bazel package which contains the mapper (using a partial sync in IntelliJ), it correctly generates the mapping code which is placed in a directory under "External Libraries". The issue, however, is that IntelliJ doesn’t recognize that the the interface I wrote (i.e. the mapper) has an implementation (i.e. the generated files).

This issue can be reproduced with the [mapstruct-on-bazel](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-on-bazel) project in IntelliJ. For reference, I have IntelliJ 2021.1.3 (Community Edition), MapStruct Support 1.3.0 plugin, and the Bazel 2021.08.24.0.0-api-version-211 plugin.

Rather than being a MapStruct problem, I think the issue is that IntelliJ does not recognize the output of annotation processors (like MapStruct) for Bazel projects.
From [configuring annotation processors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html):

> When you add annotation processors through the build scripts in Maven or Gradle projects, IntelliJ IDEA automatically enables the annotation processing and adds the appropriate paths in the annotation processor settings.

It seems that for Bazel projects (in contrast to Maven and Gradle projects) the solution might be to configure an annotation profile manually. However, I'm unsure what values to put in the annotation profile dialog or if this really is the correct way to get IntelliJ to recognize generated files for Bazel projects.

Comment: Do you use [bazel plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8609-bazel)  by google?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov yup. As mentioned in the question, I'm using Bazel plugin 2021.08.24.0.0-api-version-211.

Comment: Seems to be a plugin's bug. Try raising a bug request on their github